# Rails: HABTM association between ActiveResource and ActiveRecord class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, associations, activeresource

I am trying to implement my own methods for habtm association between ActiveResource and ActiveRecord classes in my Rails app.

Here is my classes:

```
   class Project < ActiveResource::Base
   end

   class Target < ActiveRecord::Base

   has_and_belongs_to_many :projects

   def project_ids
     project_ids
   end

  def project_ids=(pids)
    project_ids = pids
  end

  def projects
    projects = []
    pids = project_ids.split(",")
    pids.each do |pid|
      projects.push(Project.find(pid))
    end
  end

  def projects=(projs)
    pids = projs.collect(&:id)
    project_ids = pids.join(",")
  end
 end
```

I also have join table projects_targets with two columns project_id and target_id.

This does not record the association value into the join table upon creation.

My Questions:

1. Is there any other approach to do this ?
2. Am I missing something in my association methods?

I'd really appreciate any help.

Thanks in advance for help!

Comment: I recommend you use `has_many :through` over HABTM

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer @Michael Durrant. Would it even work for active resource ? Because my Project class is active resource

Comment: I do not know the answer to that, sorry.  I note that user2967130 agrees with HMT and gives more details.  An important thing with rails is to spend a lot of the time finding out how to do it the right way and (as also mentioned) not fight the framework.  This may mean spending half the day (or even longer) to end up with 4 lines of code (as opposed to spending 1 hour of adding workaround for a "working" product that is 35 lines long and inherently unstable.

Comment: No worries. Thank you for getting back on this. You are absolutely right in saying "not fight the framework". I have experienced it throughout learning rails as I am still a beginner. Thank you again!

Answer (score 1):

My advice is to not fight the framework and use the built in methods. If you wanted to implement custom accessors, then you should switch to a has many through because it will give you a model ( of the join table ) that you can work with to set the association manually.

Start here: http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-and-belongs-to-many-association

You will not need the custom accessors project_ids or projects because rails will do the work magically.

You can easily do assignments like so:

```
some_target.projects << some_project
```

You don't even have to call some_target.save because the << operator is saving the association and writing the id's to the join table for you.

If you have an array of projects, or an active record relation ( like the result of a where clause) you can pass it in the same way

```
some_target.projects << array_of_projects
```

To remove the association, you can call destroy with an object like

```
some_target.projects.destroy a_specific_project
```

This won't destroy a_specific_project, but it will un-associate it.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer @user2967130. I tried to implement the has_many :through but I get NoMethodError: undefined method `transaction' for Project:Class while trying to do some_target.projects << some_project. Thank you again for your help.